# Missing background video in network render

Tags: video, network

I am using Blender 2.78

I have a video that I've motion tracked and rendered on top of using the cycle renderer. This works fine when rendering locally. I've tried doing a network render with slave machines set up to do cycle renders and only the foreground models show up. The background is black.

In Scene, there's a Foreground layer for objects that are visible in both the local and network renders, and a background layer for shadows on the ground. Not sure if these shadows are being rendered or not in network render mode.

On computer1, I have Master, Client and Slave running. On computer2 and computer3 I have slaves running.

Is there something I need to do to send the movie clip for the background to the slaves? The locally running slave blender should at least have access to it.

Comment: In the mean time, why not render the 3d foreground as transparent images, then composite them later?

Comment: What are you using to do the network render? There are many add-ons and external tools for this.